# Authentication between Silverlight and WCF Service WITHOUT ASP.Net Auth

Tags: wcf, silverlight, authentication

Does anyone know of any best practices or 'standard' techniques for implementing authentication between a silverlight client and WCF services WITHOUT using either RIA Services or ASP.Net authentication & cookies.

My current best option seems to be to add additional message headers to each call and authenticate the user with each call. Any other ideas?

Comment: nope, that's the best way to do it. Web service calls are by design state-less and artificially introducing something session-like usually causes more grief than it solves....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the username/credential over HTTPS from SL3: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833059(VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Authenticating with each call is a good technique for scalable solutions.  One method you could look into is, one which many including some amazon web services and the likes of Ebay I think which is HMAC (Hash Message Authentication Code)

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

You need to send information with each call.

You must however make sure that the information cannot be read for example by using SSL.